# Setting Data in Main Function Defined in getInitialProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In my NextJS app, I get initial data via `getInitialProps`;

```
TvApp.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  const res = await axios.get(`http://192.168.1.2:8090/api/tv_app/:${lineId}`)
  const data = await res
  return { data: data.data }
}
```

I use that data like this;

```
export default function TvApp(data) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <h2 className={styles.bigAmount}>
        {data.data.thirdScreen[0] && data.data.thirdScreen[0].AMOUNT}
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I also want to update my view in every 10 seconds.

My problem is I cannot set the `data` previously defined in `getInitialProps`.

```
export default function TvApp(data) {
 
   useEffect((data) => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
       axios.get(`http://192.168.1.2:8090/api/tv_app/:${lineId}`)
        .then(response => ) //This line should set the data with response
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error.response.data);
        });
      return () => clearInterval(timer);
    }, 10000);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <h2 className={styles.bigAmount}>
        {data.data.thirdScreen[0] && data.data.thirdScreen[0].AMOUNT}
      </h2>
    </div>
  );

}
```

How can I set the `data` in `useEffect`?

*This is probably a very basic question but I cannot find a way.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sate variable to hold the data if it has to be updated in component

```
export default function TvApp(props) {
const [data,setData] = useState(props.data);
 
   useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
       axios.get(`http://192.168.1.2:8090/api/tv_app/:${lineId}`)
        .then(response => 
setData(response.data);
) //This line should set the data with response
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error.response.data);        });
      return () => clearInterval(timer);
    }, 10000);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <h2 className={styles.bigAmount}>
        {data.thirdScreen[0] && data.thirdScreen[0].AMOUNT}
      </h2>
    </div>
  );

}
```